# force:recordView doesn't show the mini page layout

Tags: lightning

im trying to show some details about an account when i hover above its record inside a custom component i created.
to show the details i wrote the following row:

```
<force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}" type="FULL"  />
```

and as you can see in this picture, the details appear:

[image]

the problem is when i try to display the mini page layout, it doesn't show.

```
<force:recordView recordId="{!v.recordId}" type="MINI"  />
```

[image]

if there any more code i can post to help, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: seems like its a known issue currently

Comment: Anyone has any solution to this ?

Comment: A known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ewvsQAA&title=components-using-force-recordview-type-mini-do-not-display-correctly-in-lightning-experience